Subscribing to events inside static methods
I am after some advice on if the following way of subscribing to events could give rise to memory leaks:
// Possibly in an UI class...
void Main()
{
    var myObject = Helpers.GetMyObject();
    myObject.DoWork();
}

public class MyObject
{
    public event EventHandler WorkDone;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        WorkDone?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public static class Helpers
{
    public static MyObject GetMyObject()
    {
        var myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.WorkDone += (o, i) => Console.WriteLine("Did some work!");

        return myObject;
    }
}

Thank you.

What about simply profiling it and see for yourself? Telling it for this sample does not help in understanding it for a real world app. This one directly ends after printing to the console and the process is gone hence memory is gone hence no leak.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126598/how-and-when-are-c-sharp-static-members-disposed
